# run-Jetty-run Eclipse plugin: allow only loopback connections

Tags: java, eclipse, security, eclipse-plugin, jetty

I have installed `Run Jetty Run` plugin for Eclipse.

Following [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/wiki/GettingStarted) and [User Guide](http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/wiki/UserGuide) I was able to make work with creating a new Java Project, creating `web` folder and then `WEB-INF` inside it. `WEB-INF` is an empty folder and `web` has `index.html`.

Now I want to **enable connections only via loopback interface**. My guess is that configurable via `WEB-INF\web.xml` file, but I am not able to find any documentation about that file format used by `Run Jetty Run`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this!

[In the runjettyrun's source code (runjettyrun.Bootstrap.java):](https://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/source/browse/Jetty8Support/bootstrap-jetty8/src/runjettyrun/Bootstrap.java#155)

```
private static void initConnnector(Server server, Configs configObj) {
    SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();

    //Don't set any host , or the port detection will failed. -_-#
    //connector.setHost("127.0.0.1");
    connector.setPort(configObj.getPort());

    if (configObj.getEnablessl() && configObj.getSslport() != null)
        connector.setConfidentialPort(configObj.getSslport());

    server.addConnector(connector);

    if (configObj.getEnablessl() && configObj.getSslport() != null)
        initSSL(server, configObj.getSslport(), configObj.getKeystore(),
                configObj.getPassword(), configObj.getKeyPassword(),
                configObj.getNeedClientAuth());

}
```

The plugin need to check the used port whether or not.

**The 'setHost' code was commented by the plugin author(Maybe you can hack this).**

Also there is no way to set the host in the 'Connector' interface:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector.setHost(String)
```

Comment: +1 for quick answer. So you think the only way would be to request this feature from authors?

Comment: You can build the plugin from the source. It's a open source project.

Answer (score 0):

I got hack this using the additional jetty.xml. In this jetty.xml I replaced the original connectors (created by plugin) for two "new" connectors configured as my needs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Call name="setConnectors">
    <Arg>
      <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector">
        <!-- HTTP Connector -->
        <Item>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
            <Arg name="server"><Ref id="Server" /></Arg>
            <Set name="host">127.0.0.1</Set>
            <Set name="port">80</Set>
          </New>
        </Item>

        <!-- HTTPS Connector (Optional) -->
        <Item>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
            <Arg name="server"><Ref id="Server" /></Arg>
            <Arg name="sslContextFactory">
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
                <Set name="keyStorePath">C:/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/security/cacerts</Set>
                <Set name="keyStorePassword">changeit</Set>
                <Set name="keyManagerPassword">changeit</Set>
              </New>
            </Arg>
            <Set name="host">127.0.0.1</Set>
            <Set name="port">8444</Set>
          </New>
        </Item>         
      </Array>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

In this approach the "Port", "SSL Port", "Keystore", "Password" and "Key Password" from plugin´s config screen (eclipse run configurations), will not take any effect because these configs will be defined on additional jetty.xml file.